# MongoDB installation failed on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, 16.04, mongodb

I followed instructions given on the official MongoDB website (https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) and I get this error when trying to install MongoDB. How to fix this issue and what's going wrong? Remember I'm using latest Ubuntu version 16.04

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

mongodb-org : 

Depends: mongodb-org-shell but it is not going to be installed

Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed

Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed

Depends: mongodb-org-tools but it is not going to be installed

virtualbox-5.0 : Depends: libqt4-opengl (>= 4:4.7.2) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11) but it is not going to be installed

Recommends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but it is not going to be installed

E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Edit: Title. MongDB -> MongoDB.

Comment: I tried running the install instructions posted by t9toqwerty / muru. But still got the message the following packages have unmet dependencies: What worked for me was to manually install MongoDB from the tarball: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/

Comment: Which mongodb version are you trying to install?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Install mongodb in Ubuntu 12.04, 14.04 ,16.04

1. Import the public key used by the package management system

   ```
   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2930ADAE8CAF5059EE73BB4B58712A2291FA4AD5
   ```
2. Create a list file for MongoDB.

   In Ubuntu 12.04 (deprecated):

   ```
   echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu precise/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
   ```

   In Ubuntu 14.04:

   ```
   echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list
   ```

   In Ubuntu 16.04:

   ```
   echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list
   ```
3. Reload local package database.

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

   It will throw a warning

   ```
   W: http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/trusty/mongodb-org/3.0/Release.gpg: Signature by key 492EAFE8CD016A07919F1D2B9ECBEC467F0CEB10 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
   ```

   Just Ignore It.
4. Install the MongoDB packages.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
   ```

After installation you can start MongoDB using

```
sudo service mongod start
```

To stop MongoDB use

```
sudo service mongod stop
```

To restart MongoDB use

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

If that didn't work, check here to see if any of the steps have been updated: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Comment: you are not using latest mongo 3.4 as referenced in OP mongo link

Comment: Thank you for this answer!

Answer (score 12):

TL;DR;

Try running this command,

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl3 openssl
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
```

**Logs:**

So I've followed official instructions on Mongo 4.0 [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#install-mongodb-community-edition) and got this after running `sudo apt-get install mongodb-org`

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then I manually added mongodb-org-server to installation command:

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org mongo-db-server
```

but then I got

```
mongodb-org-server : Depends: libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

After manually installing these:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl3 openssl
```

I got it working with single:

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
```

command.

Comment: @Arman glad that I could help )

Answer (score 2):

I tried running the install instructions posted by t9toqwerty / muru. But still got the message

```
the following packages have unmet dependencies:
```

What worked for me was to manually install MongoDB from the tarball. Original link is: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/

1) Download Binaries

```
curl -O https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.4.9.tgz
```

2) Extract Files

```
tar -zxvf mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.4.9.tgz
```

3) Copy Archive to Target Directory

```
mkdir -p mongodb
cp -R -n mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.4.9/ mongodb
```

4) Place location in the PATH variable.

```
export PATH=<mongodb-install-directory>/bin:$PATH
```

(Replace `<mongodb-install-directory`> with the path to the extracted MongoDB archive. For me this was /home/myusername/mongodb/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.4.9)

Next comes running it:

1) Create Data Directory

```
mkdir -p /data/db
```

2) Set Permissions

This is making sure the user has read and write permissions for the directory. Find the directory in the terminal, and enter

```
chmod 777 /data/db
```

3) Run it!

```
mongod
```

If you didn't set up the PATH variable in step 4, run mongo by entering the path to your bin file— like so

```
<path to binary>/mongod
```

Answer (score 2):

First, remove all mongo packages.

1. List all mongo packages.

`sudo apt list --installed | grep 'mongo'`

2. Remove package.

`sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove packagename`

3. Then follow the mongo installation documentation.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/

Answer (score 0):

Xenial (Ubuntu 16.04); MongoDB v. 3.2.11

```
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
apt-get -qq update   (if you are using docker)
apt-get update
apt-get install mongodb-org
```

I just did it and it was fine.

Font: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: I guess the OP is trying to install mongodb 3.6 since I had same issues when installing that version. So installing version 3.2 might not be an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same couple of days back. Try running through aptitude. This will take care of installing all the dependency packages.

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install mongodb-org
```

Answer (score 0):

I was on Ubuntu 18 (bionic) and accidentally added Ubuntu 20 repo of mongo to my repo list. I had to remove it using the (-r) parameter.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r 'deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse'
```